# Storing element state in a cookie

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies

I have a side menu `div` on my webpage. There is a requirement that if the user expands/collapses the menu, the state should be persisted when navigating to other pages (the entire page reloads)

Is it best practice to store the state in a cookie? The name/value would be base64 encoded and I've checked that clearing the cookies that results in the state being lost is acceptable

Is there an agreed way to pass values/state between pages of an application?

It is an ASP.NET application and the menu is controlled using jQuery click events

Comment: Sure, cookies are fine. localStorage or sessionStorage are also viable alternatives. At the end of the day, if all you're doing is storing the state of a menu, it makes little difference.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks so much. Do you want to answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?